# Jumping to the next "instruction" using gdb

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I am attempting to figure the canary value setting and checking mechanism.

```
#include 
int main(void)
{
        return printf("Hi!\n");
}
```

When disassemble the main, I get

```
(gdb) disas main
0x080483f4 :    lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
0x080483f8 :    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x080483fb :    pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
0x080483fe :   push   %ebp
0x080483ff :   mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048401 :   push   %ecx
0x08048402 :   sub    $0x14,%esp
0x08048405 :   mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
0x0804840b :   mov    %eax,-0x8(%ebp)
0x0804840e :   xor    %eax,%eax
0x08048410 :   movl   $0x8048500,(%esp)
0x08048417 :   call   0x8048320 
0x0804841c :   mov    -0x8(%ebp),%edx
0x0804841f :   xor    %gs:0x14,%edx
0x08048426 :   je     0x804842d 
0x08048428 :   call   0x8048330 
0x0804842d :   add    $0x14,%esp
0x08048430 :   pop    %ecx
0x08048431 :   pop    %ebp
0x08048432 :   lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
0x08048435 :   ret
```

I set a breakpoint at  0x0804840e using

```
b *0x0804840e
```

After the program flow stops at this breakpoint I would like `gdb` to go to the next **instruction** instead of next **line of c code**. I don't think I can use `next` for this. So what other option do I have apart from setting a breakpoint at every instruction?

Comment: GDB does have fairly good online help - `help` will get you a list of topics, among which is running; `help running` lists "stepi -- Step one instruction exactly", and `help stepi` gives a more detailed description.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You want to use `stepi`, aka `si`.  it steps by one machine instruction.
(Or `ni` to step over `call` instructions.)

Check the GDB manual's section on continuing and stepping, which has [an entry for it](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#index-si-_0028stepi_0029).
Or inside GDB, `help` / `help running` will show you that `si` exists, and `help stepi` will show you more about it.

Comment: I tend to use shorter `si` or `ni` aliases.